# How to delete any commit from commits table in Gitlab?

Tags: github, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit

In this `image` you can see list of `commit`, I want to `delete` one of them, but I could not find the `delete` option.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **revert**(the right nomenclature) a commit directly on Gitlab  it all you need to do is:

1. Enter the commit you want to revert by clicking on its name;
2. Click on the button **Options**;
3. Click **Revert**.

*Note that similar to reverting a Merge Request, you can opt to revert the changes directly into the target branch or create a new Merge Request to revert the changes.*

You can follow the official documentation for more details: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html#reverting-a-commit

Comment: what does it mean "revert" ?  I don't understand (:

Comment: if I open browse file in a commit. then I can not see the revert button

Comment: Did you click on the **Options** button first? Please tell me what shows up when you click on it.

Comment: Additional to @alejdg you can revert final commits, not middle commits. If you want this, you have to revert ALL previous commits